# Why is a very small percentage of the swap being used when my ubuntu is almost freezing?

Tags: unity, 14.04, swap

My Ubuntu gets very slow because of too many apps, but when i check the system monitor, Ram use is 80% but swap is less than 5%. How do you let ubuntu use the swap more effectively?

Answer (score 0):

swap area is used in a smart way: the OS decides how to use it, when you have many apps running and you use most of them at a time simeltaniously they need to be in RAM to be ready, but swap area is something like a garage. the programs which are not used at time are parked there and when you need them the Kernel will load them into memory, if your memory is going to filled up completely the Kernel move some of apps to the swap area and moving this data is time consuming. how ever if you have a fast disk such as SSD you will not notice these movements.